# Grouped NestedLists?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I create a grouped Nested List in ST2 like I would in Xcode with Storyboards?  I only need groups at the root level.  Here's some idea of what it looks like in a native app.

I didn't see anything in Sencha's NestedList [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In ST2, the NestedList method getSubList() is now getList(), and it works a bit differently. Overriding it to propagate the grouping info worked for me:

```
/**
 * Override Ext.dataview.NestedList.getList to propagate grouping info from
 * parent NestedList to List sublist.
 */
getList: function(node) {

    var list = this.callParent(arguments);

    list.grouped = this.grouped;
    list.store.setGrouper(this.getStore().config.grouper);

    return list;
}
```

Comment: In Sencha 2.2.1, you can propagate the "grouped" config to the list using `listConfig` (as in `listConfig: {  grouped: true; }`).  You can delete the line `list.grouped = this.grouped;` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Already asked here on Sencha Touch forum.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?122238-Grouped-Nested-List.

Comment: ^ Why don't you use a list and then try opening some panel on item click ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the KitchenSink example (User Interface -> List -> Grouped)
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/kitchen-sink

It's a simple list, just with a storers/grouper attribute in the store :

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
id: 'ListStore',
model: 'Contact',
sorters: 'firstName',
grouper: function(record) {
    return record.get('firstName')[0];
},
data: [...
```

And you call it in your list item settings :

```
items: [{
            width: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? null : 300,
            height: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? null : 500,
            xtype: 'list',
            store: 'ListStore',
            itemTpl: '<div class="contact"><strong>{firstName}</strong> {lastName}</div>',
            grouped: true,
            indexBar: true
        }]
```

Hope it'll help :)

Comment: That's a list, not a nested list.  Though, I guess it might come down to this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple grouped list and set a "tap" event for the group headers. On tapping the header, open another panel and show the list with items from only that group.